# Vertical height between rows

Tags: line-spacing

I want to increase the vertical height between rows. How can I do this for the all document?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



\begin{document}

I want to increase vertical height between rows. I want to increase vertical height between rows. I want to increase vertical height between rows. I want to increase vertical height between rows.

\end{document}
```

Comment: IN preamble ad `\usepackage{setspace}\ and than `\onehalspace` or for example `\setstretch{1.125}`.

Comment: @Zarko thank you